# How can I keep alive a GAM session?

Tags: genexus, genexus-gam

I have a webpage that must stay alive for a long time and respond immediately when the user interacts with it. The problem is that after about half an hour the GAM session (I think) expires and when the user interacts he is shown the Login screen. I have tried to change some settings in the IIS and web config, as well as to insert a refresh timeout in the panel, but it is not working. Is it possible to somehow increase the duration of the gam session? Or solve whatever the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

The Web Session Timeout configured in the Security Policy (GAM Backend) has to be less than or equal to the Session Timeout configured in the Web Server.

[More information](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?16338,Security%20Session%20Management%20in%20Applications%20using%20GAM)

Comment: I tried to change the "session timeout" setting it to 800 (it used to be 0), but the behavior hasn't changed. The user I'm using has the default security policy, but after about 30 minutes it falls. In the IIS I set in the web config httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000" but it's not enough. am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem and the way for the web.config configuration parameters to respond was to disable the log within the genexus application. Since when recording the client.log file inside the application directory, it caused the session variables to be reset earlier than expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUsQT.png)